# PSU for Bitmain Asic miner

Tags: asic, mining-hardware, mining-setup, antminer

I have a S3+ ASIC miner and [500w PSU](http://www.amazon.in/Circle-APFC-Gaming-cabinet-Server/dp/B00R07GFS2/ref=pd_cp_23_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=1PE10BWS06VQH4E1RQWY)

My question is that what do I need to convert a 4+4 PCI-E into a 6+2 PCI-E or two 6+2 PCI-E.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use a converter cable. They have so many on amazon: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=pci-e+converter+cable&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Apci-e+converter+cable

Comment: Thanks for your advice Jimmy Song,
I tried using various converter cables and each of the converter cable were burnt else making the main PCI-E wiring hot as hell, converting 8 pin PCI-E to two 6+2 is not a good idea.
After taking three attempts and trying different converter cables i got a new PSU which completely works fine.